# PHP and jQTouch

Tags: php, html, forms, session-variables, jqtouch

So I've got a fill out form on an HTML page passed to a PHP script. The PHP runs fine but I'm having some trouble getting the HTML on the PHP page to display. If in the body of the HTML I do `<?php echo $message; ?>` the variable displays fine. But as soon as I try to add formatting (divs and headers specifically) nothing displays on the page. Here's what I've got.

```
<?php
session_start();

//declare variables
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
$company = 'Test company';

$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
//strip of invalid chars
$date = str_replace( '/' , '.' , $date);

//fopen
$pathToMe = dirname(__FILE__);
$fileName = $pathToMe . "/days/" . $date;
$fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("Failure.");
fwrite($fileHandle, $name . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $comments . "\n" . "\n" ); 
fclose($fileHandle);

//email to company
$to = 'test@testserver.com';
$subject = 'Apointment scheduled online';
$body = "An apointment was just scheduled online.\n" . $name . "\n" . $email . "\n" . $phone . "\n" . $date . "\n" . $time . "\n" . $comments . "\n" . "\n" . "Please follow up to confirm.";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
    $companyConfirm = 'yes';
} else {
    $companyConfirm = 'no';
}

//client confirm
$to = $email;
$subject = 'Confirming your appointment';
$body = "Hello " . $name . "," . "\n" . "\n"  . "You recently booked an appointment with " . $company . " on " . $date . " at " . $time . ".\n" . "\n" . "We will follow up soon to confirm.";
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) {
    $confirm = 'yes';
} else {
    $confirm = 'no';
}

//confirm email
if ($companyConfirm = $confirm) {
    if ($companyConfirm = 'yes') {
        $message = "Your appointment has been confirmed. You will recieve a confirmation email shortly";
        print "<div id=\"jqt\"><div id=\"home\" class=\"current\"><h1>Scheduler</h1><ul class=\"edit rounded\"><li>" . $message;
    }
    else {}
} else {
    $message = "There was a problem making your appointment. Please call to schedule.";
}

$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
?>

<html>
<body>
<div id="home">
<div class="toolbar">
<h1>Scheduler</h1>
<a class="back" href="#home">Back</a>
</div>
<ul class="edit rounded">
<li><?php echo $message; ?></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts as how to get `$message` displayed inline with formatting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't see anything off hand that would make it fail, but one thing I notice is that you have `$companyConfirm = $confirm` which is probably not what you want (assignment versus equality).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried in other browsers?

It seems that you have an extra `</div>` before `</body>`

If that is the case, even if it does not show up on your browser window, you should see it if you look at the html source.

EDIT: and you also have that `print` statement which leaves a  a `li` and a lot of `div` tags opened

Answer (score 0):

What revision of jQT are you using? The current revision requires a div with an jqt ID before any content.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="jqt">
  ...
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at the demos in the official GitHub repo -> https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch